# How do I get my script to return a success message?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

"app.js" (holds all of the Firebase auth and init) and "sign-up.html" (a simple form)

However, I don't get any errors, and nothing is sent to the console to tell me that I have logged in despite using the following:

```
const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Here's app.js: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ph5e1ejr6ue1d7/app.js?dl=0 and sign-up.html: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnvn17ggxn0uckh/sign-up.html?dl=0

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: To see something like: V {R Array [0[, v: "...." in the console to show that you have successfully authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the then() method on the promise returned from [signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) to know when signup has succeeded.  Since the API tells you what happened, there's no need to expect the SDK to print something on the console.  You could log something yourself.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(user => {
    // authenticated user is available here
}).catch(error => {
    // something failed
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Doug's approach will work, but I personally prefer to [use a listener to handle the sign-in/sign-out events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log("User signed in", user);
  } else {
    console.log("No user signed in");
  }
});
```

This will handle when you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`, but (unlike the `then()` approach Doug showed) it will also fire when you reload the page.